# Passing file content from Extjs to php

Tags: php, extjs, codeigniter-2

I am looking for a way to pass some content from Extjs to php for processing but it's not working. This is what I've tried so far:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Upload a PDF File',
            width: 400,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            frame: true,
            renderTo: 'uploadForm2',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    name: 'file',
                    fieldLabel: 'PDF File',
                    labelWidth: 50,
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    anchor: '100%',
                    buttonText: 'Select File...',
                    id: 'file'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Upload',
                    handler: function(){
                        var file = Ext.getCmp('file').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];
                        var form = this.up('form');
                        form.saveFile(file);
                    }
                }
            ],

        saveFile: function(file){
            var newFile = file; // this file how can i send it to codeigniter?
            console.log(newFile);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be better off with [form.submit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit). Not sure which ext version you are using but it's basically the same.

```
form.submit({
    url:'url for upload',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(fp, o){
        // your logic after successful upload
    },
    failure: function(fp, o){
        // handle failures
    }
});
```